# Nginx Ingress: passing client certificate info to backend

Tags: flask, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I successfully implemented in my aks cluster an ingress with tls certification (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls), but I would like to pass the information contained in the client certificate to the backend.
I did try adding to my ingress the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"`, but the information seems to be missing in my request headers (I am simply printing the content of `request.headers` from my flask application). Other headers are correctly shown, e.g. `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` or `X-Forwarded-Port: 443` .

Could somebody confirm the expected behaviour of the annotation?

Do I need to configure the backend somehow with tls as well?

EDIT

I did access the ingress pod, and in the nginx config I could not find any reference to `ssl_client_s_dn`, which I would expect to be the best candidate to pass the certificate info into an header.

I tried to assign some custom headers following the steps in https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/customization/custom-headers, but also this seems not to work.

Answer (score 4):

Which version of `nginx-ingress` are you using ?

At least with version `0.30` I'm able too see the client's certificate details passed to the backend properly.

The value of `ssl_client_s_dn` is being passed as `Ssl-Client-Subject-Dn` header with default nginx controller setup, no customization needed.

Here is the content of my default `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (converted from ConfigMap)

```
# Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

        proxy_set_header ssl-client-cert        $ssl_client_escaped_cert;

        proxy_set_header ssl-client-verify      $ssl_client_verify;
        proxy_set_header ssl-client-subject-dn  $ssl_client_s_dn;
        proxy_set_header ssl-client-issuer-dn   $ssl_client_i_dn;
```

Request headers seen from backend perspective:

```
   ...
    "Ssl-Client-Issuer-Dn": "CN=example.com,O=example Inc.", 
    "Ssl-Client-Subject-Dn": "O=client organization,CN=client.example.com", 
    "Ssl-Client-Verify": "SUCCESS", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.58.0", 
    "X-Forwarded-Host": "httpbin.example.com", 
    "X-Scheme": "https", 
  }
}
```

You can always add your own custom headers, as explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/customization/custom-headers)

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  X-Client-Cert-Info: $ssl_client_s_dn
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
...
```

which reflects at backend as:

```
    ...
    "X-Client-Cert-Info": "O=client organization,CN=client.example.com", 
    "X-Forwarded-Host": "httpbin.example.com", 
    "X-Scheme": "https", 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass annotations in nginx ingress' service this

```
   annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
```

if you want modify header based on ingress rule then you may also add annotations to ingress rules as well.